# Room. Создание простейшего примера

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

В чём ошибка и как можно исправить?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.root.pets/com.example.root.pets.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.root.pets.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

---

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    internal var name: String? = null
    internal var age: Int = 0
    internal var favoriteColor: String? = null
}
```

---

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {

    // Получение всех Person из бд
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    val allPeople: List<Person>

    // Добавление Person в бд
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg people: Person)

    // Удаление Person из бд
    @Delete
    fun delete(person: Person)

    // Получение всех Person из бд с условием
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE favoriteColor LIKE :color")
    fun getAllPeopleWithFavoriteColor(color: String): List<Person>

}
```

---

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Person::class /*, AnotherEntityType.class, AThirdEntityType.class */), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val personDao: PersonDao
}
```

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myThread = Thread(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {

            var db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "populus-database4").build()

            val everyone = db.personDao
            val person = Person()
            person.name = "John Smith"
            person.age = 10000
            person.favoriteColor = "black"

            everyone.insertAll(person)
            val persons = everyone.allPeople
            Log.d("111", "${everyone.allPeople[0].name}")
        }
    })
    myThread.start()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
`@PrimaryKey` - не может быть `null`, поэтому:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var favoriteColor: String? = null
}
```

Добавить в Gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Поправил сам вопрос. Сделал добавление записи и вывода в лог `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в gradle файл и добавьте строчку, найдите annotationProcessor строчку и добавьте такую же только со словом kapt.
Вот пример

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```